# How to use long variables name in Makefile?

Tags: make, variable

Today I'm learning `make` command, and I find it seems can execute any `bash` command by reading `Makefile` on current directory.

However, I encountered a problem. That when using variables, it seems that system will only read the first character of the variable.

Below is my file and running result:

```
# FILE CONTENT
Z="zen_on_the_moon"
now=$(date)

fun:
    touch $Z
    echo $now
    echo "file created on" $now >> $Z

# RUNNING IT
=>make fun
touch "zen_on_the_moon"
echo ow
ow
echo "file created on" ow >> "zen_on_the_moon"
```

How should I use the variable `now` in the `Makefile` under `fun` item?

Comment: `makefile` syntax seems to fit perfectly on a unix topic (as would `bash` `sed` or `awk`) . I see no reason to close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `Makefile`, you [refer to a variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reference.html#Reference) by using syntax `$(var_name)`. Using `$var_name` cause the first character other than a dollar sign `$`, open parenthesis `(` or open brace `{` treated as variable name.

In `$now`, you actually get content of variable `$n` followed by literal string `ow`.

So you need:

```
$(now)
```

to get the content of variable named `now`.

Also note that `now=$(date)` get the content of variable named `date` instead of result of command `date`. You need to use [shell function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html#Shell-Function):

```
now=$(shell date)
```

Comment: Please note that this answer applies to GNU make. You can actually use braces (`{` and `}`) instead of parentheses (`(` and `)`) to refer to variables (this is mentioned in the manual linked). In other `make` implementations, there is not always a `shell` function. For example, in FreeBSD or OpenBSD `make`, you would use `FOO != some command` to set a variable to the output of a shell command.